# Redhat 7.5, rhel, ibm x3850 x5 node2 512g

Tags: linux, centos, kernel, ibm, rhel

есть проблема с установкой и запуском redhat 7.5 на сервер ibm x3850 x5 node 1 и 2. В общем, сервер перезагружается на моменте загрузки ядра, в логах ошибок нет, прерывается всегда на разном, в логах ibm пишется что сервер выключился и включился.

Но есть удачные загрузки, но они происходят совершенно не предсказуемо, очень рандомно, мб даже ни разу не включится, когда система загружается проблем не наблюдается, частота удачных загрузок увеличивается, если поставить параметры ядру mem=1024M nr_cpus=2(с такими параметрами где то через раз загружается).

Если ставить на одну ноду проблема сохраняется, но значительно реже. Причём rhel6 залетает на ура и работает, Ubuntu и VMware тоже, проблема только с CentOS и redhat.

Прошу помощи у вас :)

Comment: Я бы сначала проверил все прошивки на сервере и изъял, если всё обновлено то можно изъять лишние карты и память для запуска в минимальной конфигурации с целью проверки железа

Comment: Прошивки обновил все, с одной картой запускается, то есть с 32 об оперативки запускается, начинаешь увеличивать, увеличивается и частота перезагрузок

Comment: Возможно что-то с памятью, хоть она и ECC но это тоже не всегда спасает, может банальный перегрев памяти

Comment: full mem test ничего не показал, не завис и сделал 3 проходки за выходные

Comment: А в логах есть что-то про причины перезагрузки ? просто если это не железо то в логах должны быть хоть какие-то намёки на причину ребута.

Comment: В логах на удивление ничего нет. В message, kernel и т.п исследовал все просто сразу рестарт, это происходит только с ядром redhat CentOS